# Is MIMO equivalent to link aggregation?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, layer1, lte, 5g

Is MIMO the wireless version of link aggregation in wired networks?

I'm not asking if MIMO is a similar link aggregation protocol like LACP or PAgP, what I'm asking is if it is the same concept as bonding multiple links to act as one channel.

Let's say for example we have a pair of 2 x 2 MIMO transmitter and receiver. If the transmitter is to send two packets to the receiver does it mean packet 1 will be sent through antenna 1 and packet 2 will be sent through antenna 2 simultaneously, and the receiver will receive packet 1 through antenna 1 and packet 2 through antenna 2 simultaneously?

If yes, how do the two signals not interfere with each other? Is it because they are **orthogonal signals**? Also, is **OFDM** *always required* in MIMO because it is the only way to generate orthogonal signals?

If no, then how does MIMO increase capacity? What is the main point if MIMO?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

MIMO is different from LACP or static LAG in that it is located lower, within the physical layer.

LAG bonds multiple physical links to a single *logical* one. It sits *above* the physical layer.

MIMO extends the bandwidth of a physical link via multipath propagation over multiple antennas. It is somewhat similar to multi-lane wired links like the four-lane 1000BASE-T. However, MIMO uses a dynamic scheme while wired Ethernet uses a static setup (ie. 1000BASE-T doesn't work with two or three lanes), and of course, wireless and wired communication are very different.